# Tomcat webapp stops working for no reason: The requested resource is not available

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have a simple Tomcat webapp setup with Eclipse and when trying to access a servlet I get:

```
The requested resource is not available.
```

I can fix this problem by creating a new project, and copying every file into the new project (web.xml, html file, java servlet). However, this problem has occurred many times (with unknown causes) and I cannot afford having to create a new project every time.

I did try restarting Eclipse, cleaning the project (Project > Clean), restarting the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to deploy your application to Tomcat

Comment: I always just do Run > Run as > Run on Server. And it works... except when it doesn't.

Comment: Your application is deployed in X:apache-tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\ (X is your drive). Please check again.